# Get all entries of a class

Tags: ruby

I made an application where a `Patient` has a name etc.

```
class Patient
 attr_accessor :vorName

 def initialize (vorname, name, alter)
@vorname = vorname
@name = NameName
@alter = alterr
end
```

I created two patients:

```
a = Patient.new('jonas', 'leiti', '25.02.95')
b = Patient.new('emanuel','stadler', '59.09.91')
```

I don't know how I can get the `vorname` of all patients. I tried something like this:

```
 Patient.each do
puts vorname
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this method - [**ObjectSpace#each_object**](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ObjectSpace.html#each_object-class_method)

```
class Patient
 attr_accessor :vorname

 def initialize (vorname, name, alter)
  @vorname = vorname
  @name = name
  @alter = alter
 end 
end 

a = Patient.new('jonas', 'leiti', '25.02.95') 
b = Patient.new('emanuel','stadler', '59.09.91')

ObjectSpace.each_object(Patient) {|x| p x.vorname }
# >> "emanuel"
# >> "jonas"
```

Comment: IM working with rhinitis and get this error: >> [Running editor script (rfrank2.rb)]
=> RuntimeError: ObjectSpace is disabled; each_object will only work with Class, pass -X+O to enable
  each_object at org/jruby/RubyObjectSpace.java:173
       (root) at rfrank2.rb:23
nil
>>

Comment: @EmSta Its working in my case. This is the good way to go for such things. I don't know why it is not working in your case.

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as the best answer.  Definitely check out @Jeffrey's answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17629915/107277

Comment: @MattHuggins but what's the problem with this one too ?let me know that. very curious to know the fact.

Comment: As Jeffrey's answer states: "Don't use reflection/introspection unless it is absolutely necessary."  The class is attempting to reveal `vorname` as an accessor (though the casing is off in the question), so that should just be used instead.

Comment: @MattHuggins But If I use this `ObjectSpace` method,what would be the side-effect for the same ?

Comment: Why not just this then?  `ObjectSpace.each_object(Patient) { |x| p x.vorname }`

Comment: @MattHuggins Humm... done. But I don't understand the point of why not to use `#instance_variable_get`. Curious to know that fact really.

Comment: Something that's happening outside of the class should not need to know the internals of how the class works.  The fact that the `vorname` method is stored `@vorname` is an implementation detail.  If you later changed how vorname is stored, you'd also have to change all the places where you call `instance_variable_get`.  By calling the method directly, you don't have to worry about changing all your calls if the class ever changes.  Also, it's more testable this way.

Comment: @MattHuggins Thank you very much for you Excellent explanations.. *+100* to you from me... Again thanks to let me know this and for helping me to make my answer perfect. :))

Comment: For sure!  Changed my downvote to an upvote with the change to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The real point is: why don't you store an array of them at creation time? Instead of:

```
a = Patient.new('jonas', 'leiti', '25.02.95') 
b = Patient.new('emanuel','stadler', '59.09.91')
```

do:

```
arr = []
arr << Patient.new('jonas', 'leiti', '25.02.95')
arr << Patient.new('emanuel','stadler', '59.09.91')
```

Then you can access them with:

```
arr.each do |x|
    puts x.vorname
end
```

A good rule of thumb is:

> Don't use reflection/introspection unless it is absolutely necessary.

This is surely not the case.

*Note: `attr_accessor :vorName` should be `attr_accessor :vorname`.*

Answer (score 0):

You code contain some typos. I edited your code as follow.

```
class Patient
  attr_accessor :vorname

  @@patients = []

  def self.patients
    @@patients
  end

  def initialize (vorname, name, alter)
    @vorname = vorname
    @name = name
    @alter = alter
    @@patients.push self
  end
end


a = Patient.new('jonas', 'leiti', '25.02.95')
b = Patient.new('emanuel','stadler', '59.09.91')

Patient.patients.each do |patient|
  puts "vorname: #{patient.vorname}"
end
```

Comment: yes it works like this but my aim was that I don't have to refer to a and b but simply become all patients

Comment: I like the work-around... :)

Comment: Much more clean @falsetru, nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Patient.each do
  puts vorname
end
```

for this:

```
Patient.all.each do |patient|
  puts patient.vorname
end
```

it can also work as oneliner:

```
Patient.all.each{|patient| puts patient.vorname}
```

**EDIT**

**As Priti said down in the comments this is no rails** (my bad, if you were using rails that's the way to go though), so in plain ruby you need to use the ObjectSpace as he said in another answer.

You should replace my `Patient.all` for `ObjectSpace.each_object(Patient)` in my answer to work in plain Ruby.

Comment: There is no `#all` method in *Ruby*. This question is tagged with *Ruby*.

Comment: Im working with ruboto android and I always get the error : >> [Running editor script (rfrank2.rb)]
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for Patient:Class
  (root) at rfrank2.rb:23
nil
>>